# Is it possible to force an interface to be implemented only by enums?

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to know if it's possible to force an interface to be implemented by an enum.

I have the following interface:

```
public interface MobileApplication {
    String name();
}
```

This should be implemented by an enum because i need garantee on the uniqueness of the name.
As i am designing a library i can't trust the library users, and without an unique name, my library will not work at all.

I can do without with security, just wonder if it's possible.
Thanks

Comment: You can't stop annonations being implemented by classes.  There is any amount of madness developer can get up to. BTW: you can have two enums which both implement the interface with the same name, so I don't believe this will give you what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't really do this at compile-time. You can give *hints* at this by requiring methods like `ordinal()` and `name()` or you can check it at *runtime*.

Regarding "I can't trust the library users": as long as you document the requirement in the interfaces JavaDoc, anyone who doesn't follow it gets what they paid for.

That's exactly the same as if someone didn't implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly: the compiler doesn't enforce it, but if you break it, then classes that depend on them break as well.

The closest you can get is probably something like this:

```
public interface EnumInterface<E extends Enum<E>> {
}
```

where the implementation would look like this:

```
public enum MyInterfaceImpl implements EnumInterface<MyInterfaceImpl> {
  FOO,
  BAR;
}
```

It's just another *hint*, since a "malicious" developer could still build a class like this:

```
class NotAnEnum implements EnumInterface<MyInterfaceImpl> {
}
```

All in all, there will always be ways to mis-use any library. The library authors goal is to make it *easier* to use the library correctly than it is to use the library incorrectly. You don't need to make it *impossible* to use it incorrectly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will add that ordinal() method, it should discourage people to misuse my library :)

Comment: Sidenote: it might be better to require whatever properties of an enum you require instead of requiring an enum itself in the documentation. You can mention that using an `enum` is the easiest way to ensure those, but occasionally there are reasons to implement such interfaces as non-enums. It's hard to think of all possible use-cases for a library when designing them. Quoting the *real* requirements instead of the easiest way to implement them can help the library users be flexible and *still* have an easy way to use your library if they don't need that flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. Unless you are going to provide a Java compiler plugin that would specifically check this. But even then, the users of your library would need to be willing to use such plugin.

Therefore, the approach with a custom Java compiler plugin makes sense only if the library users wish to have some static assistance tool to prevent error. [This link](http://in.relation.to/10262.lace) might be of interest in case you'll decide to go with the Java plugin option.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to force an interface to be
>   implemented by an enum.

No, it is not. Interfaces can be implemented by any class and you cannot force the user of your library to use an enum.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to force an interface to be implemented by an enum.

Even if you could it wouldn't help because

> without an unique name, my library will not work at all.

```
enum A implements MobileApplication {
    ONE
}
enum B implements MobileApplication {
    ONE
}
enum C implements MobileApplication {
    ONE
}
```

You have three enum values, all with a `name()` or `ONE`.

Comment: That's true thanks. Btw my library would work but not as expected and would be hard to identify the problem

Comment: @SebastienLorber Can you include the class name with the name? This would be unique (with one class loader)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work in all application cases, but formulating a library to use generics could be a way out for people in future writing libraries and looking at this question.

For example, I wanted to write a library class (SettingsManagerBase) that generically manages my application 'settings', and wanted guaranteed unique keys to be able to get/set these settings in code. So I defined my interface (here I have also incorporated the idea from the accepted answer for extra 'security', but this is not strictly speaking necessary with my approach):

```
// Part of my settings library
public interface SettingBase<E extends Enum<E>> {
    Object defaultValue();  // <-- Whatever interface is needed
}
```

And my implementation:

```
// Part of my application that uses the settings library
public enum Setting implements SettingBase<Setting> {
    THEME,
    SHOW_DIALOGS,
    ...;

    @Override
    public Object defaultValue() { ... }  // <-- Required interface implementation, probably based on constructor arguments (not shown)
}
```

Now the crux, our settings manager library class specifies that it MUST be given an enumeration that implements SettingBase (this is now a total guarantee):

```
// Part of my settings library
public abstract class SettingsManagerBase<E extends Enum<E> & SettingBase<E>> {
    public void foo(E setting) {
        Object d = setting.defaultValue();  // We can safely use all methods from our interface
        String n = setting.name();          // We can safely use all enumeration methods, without needing to specify them manually in our interface or anything
    }
}
```

The settings manager implementation can then be:

```
// Part of my application that uses the settings library
public class SettingsManager extends SettingsManagerBase<Setting> {
    // If you need to override a function then E just turns into Setting
    public void foo(Setting setting) { ... }
}
```

If you need the class instance corresponding to the generic Enum 'E' in the library class (SettingsManagerBase), then you can do:

```
// Add to SettingsManagerBase
protected Class<E> mEnumClass;
public SettingsManagerBase(Class<E> enumClass) {
    mEnumClass = enumClass;
    // Now you can do things like call Enum.valueOf(...)
}

// Add to SettingsManager
public SettingsManager() {
    super(Setting.class);
}
```

I know this answer seems specific to my use case, but it should not be hard to implement this idea for many other situations that want to force an interface to be implemented by an enumeration.